# How can Solve problems while debugging sharepoint web application?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, web-config, debugging, application-pool

Everytime I try to run my sharepoint application in debug mode, I get the error bellow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And have you tried what they suggest? repair visual studio...?

Comment: Can you add some more detail like what sort of application and how do you debug the application? I hope you are attaching your program to w3wp process

Comment: Visual Studio uses internal web server called Cassini, I think that is broker... Reinstalling or Repairing Visual Studio should fix the issue!